# Правильный синтаксис присваивания переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Необходимо обновленную таблицу присвоить новой переменной. Можно в одну строку, а как сделать, чтобы было в несколько строк. В скобках `calls` также выдает ошибку.

```
calls = 
( 
    df_calls
    .groupby(['user_id', 'month'])
    ['duration']
    .agg(['count', 'sum'])
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: `calls = \ ` для переноса строки, а скобки там не нужны

Comment: А по-подробней можно? Не пойму)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правило такое: Когда разделить команду на 2 или более строк, надо Питон предупредить, что *команда еще не завершилась и будет продолжаться на следующей строке:*

- знаком `\` как последним в текущей строке,
- но этого *не надо сделать* когда продолжение строки следует *неявно*

  - из отсутствия (пока) заключающей (т.е. правой) *круглой скобки,*
  - из отсутствия (пока) заключающей (т.е. правой) *квадратной скобки,*
  - из отсутствия (пока) заключающей (т.е. правой) *фигурной скобки.*

---

Пример:

```
calls = (
    df_calls
    .groupby(['user_id', 'month'])
    ['duration']
    .agg(['count', 'sum'])
    .reset_index()
    )
```

Не надо (но возможно) писать ни одного `\`, потому что всё время ждется правая круглая скобка - к первой левой скобке в первой строке.

---

См. рекомендацию

> Предпочтительный способ переноса длинных строк является использование подразумеваемых продолжений строк Python внутри круглых, квадратных и фигурных скобок. Длинные строки могут быть разбиты на несколько строк, обернутые в скобки. Это предпочтительнее использования обратной косой черты для продолжения строки.

в части [Максимальная длина строки](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#section-5) в документе [PEP 8 - руководство по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html).

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так должно работать. Продолжение кода на следующей строке в питоне осуществляется с помощью бэкслэша:

```py
calls = \
    df_calls \
    .groupby(['user_id', 'month']) \
    ['duration'] \
    .agg(['count', 'sum']) \
    .reset_index()
```

Возможно, где-то `\` можно и не писать, но это нужно проверять.